# нужно найти функцию OpenCV (если такая существует), подходящую к описанию

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

OpenCV. Есть код, обнаруживающий объект по определенным параметрам, после чего нужно далее следить за объектом, но обрабатывать все изображение полностью занимает много времени, поэтому было решено обрабатывать кусок изображения лишь в той части где был объект, если его уже там нет, то переход к полной обработке изображения снова.

Не могли бы подсказать функцию в OpenCV, которая могла бы "обрезать" все изображение к центру найденного обьекта...

Comment: посмотрите в этой статье, возможно поможет вам https://tproger.ru/translations/opencv-python-guide/#crop

Comment: уже смотрел, неа

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно установить регион интереса (ROI), для чего в С++ интерфейсе есть специальные функции. В Python же используется двумерный срез

```
roiimg = img[x1:x1+wdt,y1:y1+hgt]
```